# Value Error when entering formula

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, formula, array-formulas

My code works fine in my test sheet, but when i enter it in my active sheet i get a value error...any suggestions?
I really don't know what i'm doing wrong, literally pulling my hair out.
Any help as to why im getting this error will be greatly appreciated.

the below code works perfectly in my test sheet and returns all values correctly, somehow when I enter it in the sheet that matters, boom value error.

```
=IF(J5="YES",SUM((E10:I610>11538)*(E10:I610<=34760)*(A10:A610="No")*ROUND(E10:I610*0.056,0))+SUM((E10:I610>34760)*ROUND(34760*0.056,0)),0)
```

Comment: My guess is either that it's not entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter or that there is a non-numeric value somewhere in E10:I610.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Doug - assuming you don't have errors in the referenced ranges it looks like #VALUE! error would only be caused by trying to apply a `ROUND` function to a text value - this version should avoid that error

`=IF(J5="YES",SUM(IF(E10:I610>11538,IF(E10:I610<=34760,IF(A10:A610="No",ROUND(E10:I610*0.056,0)),IF(ISNUMBER(E10:I610),ROUND(34760*0.056,0))))),0)`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

.....but check the result because the fix might effect the expected result

Note: if E10:I610 is > 34760 then the sum includes 34760*0.056 rounded (i.e. 1947) regardless of the column A value (as per your formula). Is that the intent?

Re your comment - this revised version should do what you want

`=IF(J5="YES",SUM(IF(E10:I610>11538,IF(A10:A610="No",IF(ISNUMBER(E10:I610),ROUND(IF(E10:I610>34760,34760,E10:I610)*0.056,0))))),0)`

Comment: Great observation...this is not my intention, I need that condition to take into consideration the column A value just as the others. Only if the column A value is "No" only then should that value be calculated. Please rewrite the formula to give consideration for this condition if you can. Thanks.

Comment: =IF(J5="YES",SUM(IF(E10:I610>11538,IF(E10:I610<=34760,IF(A10:A610="No",ROUND(E10:I610*0.056,0)),IF(ISNUMBER(E10:I610),IF(A10:A610="No",ROUND(34760*0.056,0))))),0))...This seems to be working.

Thanks a million Barry, your solution is spot on.

Answer (score 1):

It is an array formula, so use Ctrl-Shift-Enter rather than Enter to complete it.

Comment: yes Andrew I used the Ctrl-Shift-Enter to enter it. This is baffling me.

Comment: Did you look into Doug's suggestion? Make sure that all the cells feeding the formula contain *suitable* values. Hint: Ctrl-[ (left square bracket) is a useful shortcut, highlighting precedent cells. You could use this shortcut, then Ctrl-G, click Special, select Constants and change the ticks below to just Text; this will select any cells containing Text.

Comment: .. you could even then press 0 (or whatever value is suitable), Ctrl-Enter to enter this to all the (formerly) text cells, then Ctrl-] to jump back to the original formula ;)

Comment: so i placed the formula piece by piece and it seems to be getting the problem here *ROUND(E10:I610*0.056,0)

Comment: Andrew has already asked, but did you look into my educated guess that you have non-numeric values somewhere in E10:I610? That really should be your next step. It will produce the #VALUE error with your formula.

Comment: @DougGlancy temporarily over-writing the cells with sensible numbers could also help to prove whether this is the issue.